# multicast/broadcast rate-limit in Linux bridge (kernel)

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming

I need to come up with some solution to drop some Multicast packet smartly in linux kernel - typically in bridge.

I already have parser to get pkt info - so I can forward ARP/DHCP/IGMP-MLD/mDNS and other important multicast/broadcast packets without having this rate limit. I only need to do a rate limit with unknown-multicast traffic....

I cannot do it on "egress interface" and I should drop the packet as soon as possible in ingress. So, I decided to do it before backlog queue in the bridge.

Which open-source package/tool can I use for this purpose? Any advice? I reviewed TC(it's on egress) and iptables/ebtables but all these are not good for my purpose.

Please give any advice if you have anything...... Thanks in advance.